# Sublime Text incorrectly parses code

Tags: sublimetext2

In C++ source files, our coding standards dictate that we declare functions like:

```
void            InputJournalManager::RecordFocusChange
(
WindowInfo * windowP, 
int reason
)
    {
    ...
    }
```

When I do this, navigating by symbol will fail to pick this up as a method to jump to.  The issue seems to be having the argument list declared on separate lines.  Also, it seems there is no support for parsing C++/CLI as anything that takes a ref class (or returns one) will fail to be recognized.  Is there any way I can go about fix this?